# Responder Object - How to get Function name AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, netconnection

I'm using NetConnection object to make my PHP calls from AS3. The call() method receives a Responder Object to know which function will deal with the response from PHP.
What I want to know is if it's possible to know what is the name of the Function and the class/file that this function is in (assuming that I have a reference of the Responder Object).

Comment: Not sure I am following your question. When you use `NetConnection.call()`, you can optionally pass in a `Responder` object that you have instantiated. *You must create the responder*. Since you are creating it, you must know the function/class names. Are the names unkown b/c you're using a library that is handling the result for you?

Comment: I'm building a Bridge between the call() and the user of NetConnection's class. My intents are the following: One call will be made to PHP. If there's an error on the Server Side, I wanna be able to export all information about the call that was made (Command, Responder and Parameters) to a .json file that the user will download. After the Server problem is fixed, the user will be able to upload the .json file and the call will be automatically made again, preventing rework.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The API for the `Responder` doesn't include any way to access the result/fault handler methods. However, you can extend the `Responder` class to add that functionality.